# Which event should be cancelled to stop a contenteditable keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to build around contenteditable by first disabling it's text styling behavior from keyboard shortcuts, such as `ctrl+b` or `ctrl+i`.

I am using `event.preventDefault()` when these shortcuts are detected on `keyup` and `keydown` events -- however sometimes *rarely*, I am noticing that contenteditable still ignores `event.preventDefault()` and the keyboard shortcut is respected.

Is there any way I can fully disable these keyboard shortcuts other than cancelling `keyup` and `keydown`?

---

My shortcut detector was faulty and it was letting the event go through at certain cases. It seems cancelling the event on `keydown` does actually cancel the shortcut as well.

I have created a jsfiddle for anyone who wants to try it: https://jsfiddle.net/mohj19bs/28/

I will be closing this thread tomorrow, just in case someone else might share something interesting since `contenteditable` never ceased to surprise me.

Comment: Why are you using both `keyup` and `keydown`? By the way, `keyup` won't work, because, think about it. When you press `Ctrl`+`T` or `Ctrl`+`S`, before you move your finger off the keyboard the action you wish is already in motion. I would probably just use `keyup`. Could you include some code?

Comment: @code I cancelled the event on `keyup` because only cancelling on `keydown` wasn't always doing the trick, so I figured. But you are right, you can hit `Ctrl`+`B` and while both keys are completely pressed, by default, the effect will kick in -- which means cancelling `keydown` should do the trick, but sometimes rarely contenteditable styles the text anyway! I will create a nice jsfiddle later.

Comment: Watch out for `keypress` event, also. It still pops its head up on [certain browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=keypress), and some code out there still acts upon it.

Comment: @terrymorse yes, I thought of that too, but I didn't really give much thought to it because keyboard shortcuts are generally listened for with `keydown`, but it may do in more interesting scenarios like this one...

Comment: Could you show some code so we could figure out when the problem occurs and debug from there?

Comment: ok I am building a small editor right now in jsfiddle. @code

Comment: I just realized, my shortcut detector function was faulty :( When you press these keys and keep them pressed in the same order `Ctrl`+`Any`+`I` my function was failling to identify it as a keyboard shortcut for italic and thus was letting the event go through. I am sorry everyone -- cancelling shortcuts on 'keydown' seems to do the job very well actually.

Comment: It was the OPs (me) mistake and the code was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what problem you're dealing with, but this works well...

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if(!e.ctrlKey) return;
  if(e.keyCode === 66 || e.keyCode === 73) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable>This div is editable</div>
```

And a one-liner for your enjoyment:

```js
document.getElementById("test").onkeydown = e => !(e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 66 || e.keyCode === 73));
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable>This div is editable</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another strategy that may work for you. Instead of trying to prevent `b` and `i` elements from being inserted, just remove them right away on `keyup` or on `paste`.

Handled cases are:

- [CTRL] + [b] and [CTRL] + [i]
- pasted HTML which contains inline style attribute

And it works recursively to take care of nested elements.

```js
let forbiddenTags = ["B", "I", "STRONG"]
let clean = function(e){

  // Loop through all child nodes
  e.target.childNodes.forEach(function(item){
  
    // recursion if there are childnodes
    if(item.childNodes){
      clean({target:item})
    }
    
    // Remove forbidden tags
    if(item.tagName && forbiddenTags.indexOf(item.tagName) > -1){
      item.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", item.innerHTML)
      item.remove()
      return
    }
    
    // Reset inline style
    if(item.style){
      item.style.fontWeight = "normal"
      item.style.fontStyle = "normal"
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("keyup", clean)
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("paste", clean)
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contentEditable=true>Enter text here</div>
<br>
Paste me in!:
<div id="pasteit">
  <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i> <strong>strong</strong> <span style="font-weight:bold;">inline</span>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-style:italic;">Italic</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Bold</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but in my opinion it's **horrible UX**. I think a user will attempt to bold it, it works, says yay, goes "where in the world did my bold text go"? After trying it for 3 or 4 times the user reports a bug saying that "whenever I bold something it unbolds it." Happy dev, mad consumer.

Comment: @code: An `alert` or a nice looking modal can easilly be shown to tell the user bold and italic are not allowed.

Comment: that's true, but before I learned to code, some websites I used had contenteditable divs, where when I pasted HTML instead of prevent the paste it immediately stripped it. There's still the split-second flash of the HTML showing. Although I wasn't a developer, I got really annoyed and thought whoever made the website did a bad job; it was also clear that I wasn't allowed to paste HTML, but I still hated how it worked. I won't say this answer itself is bad, but the UX really gets on my nerves. It would be a lot nicer to make it so that the bold text never shows up.

Comment: @code: From start... Why not allowing bold and italic is the real question. ;)

Comment: This somewhat works but with this solution you are still exposed to contenteditable's black magic -- which means bold is handled differently (ie by wrapping it in b or strong, or using inline) according to different browsers/cases.

Comment: I edited to care about those cases.

Comment: Edited again to take care of nested elements.

Comment: Loys, your solution works but it just kills the specified text styles blindly. The use cases for such solution are extremely small, since every contenteditable content has to be processed & stored in some type of a data format.  The correct solution is to prevent the contenteditable from ever applying a text style, so we don't have to deal with inconsistent markup hell when we process it's contents. That would also solve the UX issues mentioned by @code.  I have updated my question to reflect on my new findings.